# Cypress - how to best test a multi step flow process

Tags: cypress

Using an example scenario where a user needs to shop for flights, via these Steps:

1. Select Outbound Flight, go to next page
2. Select Return Flight, go to next page
3. Enter Billing Info, go to next page
4. On The confirmation page - submit info

Now I know that Cypress is all about building up state programmatically rather than going through the steps via the UI. So for the smoke test would I want to only start the test from Step 4, feed it a previously set state and make sure there is no error upon submit?

Also what about the other pages - would it be ok to have one end to end test that goes through Steps 1-4 purely via the UI?

Comment: I'd also love to know the answer as I also have a mutli-step flow process that involves invoking 3 different APIs.

Comment: @Alex.A  See the accepted answer, and my comment in the accepted answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 ways of potentially achieving this.

1. Using Rest API in `cy.route`, 
More info here: https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/route.html#Usage

2. If the site appends query parameters to the url e.g. `www.flightsight.com/?from=london&to=chicago`, you can give this URL in step 4.

If the site uses POST request, then these parameters unfortunately won't be available.

Comment: I did end up using `cy.route` in the end. To elaborate, you would want to first run the test manually and submit the form data from Step 3 to Step 4. Then check what response your API gives when you click submit on Step 3. Then you would use `cy.route` to mock that response by providing it a <json> file with that api response.

Comment: My solution at the end was making the global timeout big enough to account for the delay on the API due to CPU load.

Comment: I've got the same question, but we've got a one-page application so changing the "page" is not done using HTTP parameters and no manual testing is possible, it all has to be done automatically. I'm thinking about asking the question again for "one-page" applications. Also we're using a process engine (BPMN) so the "state" is normally stored in this process engine.